# SQL: Find out the expense that each customer has made through card and cash

Tags: sql

I have three tables:

```
transactions
customers
credit card
```

[image]

Here, If you look at the transaction table entries, entries with the same tran_id are for transactions done by the same customer. Tran_seq_nbr gives the sequence of transactions done by that customer.

I want to find out the expense that each customer has made through card and cash and result will look like this:

Solution Example

[image]

I tried the query as:

```
    SELECT c.Cust_id, c.Cust_name, t.Card_no, IFNULL(t.card_type,'Cash_Payment') card_type, sum(t.Tran_sold_amt)
    FROM transactions t
    LEFT JOIN cards cd
    ON t.card_no = cd.card_no
    LEFT JOIN customers c
    ON c.cust_id = cd.cust_id
```

I'm not able to link card no back to cust_id as my query doen't show desired details for record: 
John Doe name as card no is 125.

Please advice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with both MySQL and SQL Server?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Your query is correct and the shown example solution is incorrect, because you don't pay cash with a Visa card (which card #125 would suggest).

Comment: Please tag your request with your DBMS. And next time please show your data as plain text (i.e. copy and paste your data), instead of images.

Comment: At a quick glance. The transaction table seems to require an extra cust_id column. To know who the customer is when they payed cash.  It makes sense that the card_no would be null when no card was used. But ok, I guess the challenge here is to find the card_no for the same tran_id, and derive the customer from that.

Comment: Here, CREDIT_CARD table is linked with CUSTOMER table via CUST_ID and we can join this by CARD_NO in TRANSACTION table. In TRANSACTION table TRAN_ID is same for a customer and TRAN_SEQ_NBR gives transaction sequence number of that transaction. We can trace the customer using CARD_NO.
I'm not to join based on this condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an odd data model.  You have to go through the credit card to get the customer, but some transactions are partially in cash and partially by credit card.

In any case, you can impute a credit card using window functions and `join`.  And then aggregate:

```
select cu.Cust_id, cu.Cust_name, t.Card_no,
       coalesce(t.card_type, 'Cash_Payment') as card_type,
       sum(t.Tran_sold_amt)
from (select t.*,
             max(t.Card_no) over (partition by Tran_id) as imputed_card_no
      from transactions t
     ) t left join
     cards ca
     on t.imputed_card_no = ca.card_no left join
     customers cu
     on cu.cust_id = ca.cust_id
group by cu.Cust_id, cu.Cust_name, t.Card_no,
       coalesce(t.card_type, 'Cash_Payment');
```

Note:  This returns `NULL` for the `card_no` for cash payments.  That makes sense to me.  If you really want the imputed card number, you can use:

```
`coalesce(t.card_no, imputed_card_no)`
```

Answer (score 0):

When transaction is cash payment (i.e. card_no is null) then get a card number of the same transactionid

```
SELECT c.Cust_id, c.Cust_name, t.Card_no, IFNULL(t.card_type,'Cash_Payment') card_type, sum(t.Tran_sold_amt)
from
(
select *, isnull(Card_no, min(Card_no) over(partition by Tran_id)) as cardnotran
from transactions 
) as t
JOIN cards cd ON t.cardnotran = cd.card_no
JOIN customers c ON c.cust_id = cd.cust_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a correlated query inside a subquery for the transactions, to get a card number for the same 'cash' transaction.

*(untested notepad scribble)*

```
SELECT cust.Cust_id, cust.Cust_name, trans.Card_no,
COALESCE(trans.card_type, 'Cash_Payment') AS card_type,
SUM(trans.Tran_sold_amt) AS TotalSoldAmount
FROM 
(
   SELECT tran_id, Card_no, card_type, Tran_sold_amt
   , (SELECT MAX(tr2.card_no) FROM transactions tr2 WHERE tr2.tran_id = tr.tran_id AND tr.card_no IS NULL) AS CardNo2
   FROM transactions tr
) trans
LEFT JOIN cards card
  ON card.card_no = COALESCE(trans.card_no, trans.CardNo2)
LEFT JOIN customers cust
  ON cust.cust_id = card.cust_id
GROUP BY cust.Cust_id, cust.Cust_name, trans.Card_no, trans.card_type
```